# WPF Adding to MenuItem

Tags: wpf, menuitem

If I have a list of MenuItems based on a List of strings using DataTemplate and ItemsSource. How do I add another MenuItem to that programatically. The added MenuItem is not a string but a TextBox. Is this even possible?

Comment: DataTemplateSelector is the answer. I was able to create 2 templates and depending on the value in the string, I was able to attach a textbox to the menuitems. But now how Do I get hold of the value from that textbox when a menuitem is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

instead of taking List of strings take Observablecollection of strings... so that you can further add new items which will recreate menu items  .